# Get storage type if disk of vm is premium or standard using get-azurermvm

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I'm an IT pro and writing a script which gives the output of vm name, vm size, and the data disk size which is attached.

Below is the command which I'm using for unmanaged and managed disk vm both. I wanted to know if i can use the get-azurermvm somehow to get the details of the disk type which is attached if it is SSD or HDD?

```
    $allvm = Get-Azurermvm | ForEach-Object { 
 $props = [ordered]@{
                    "Name" = $_.name
                    "Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.disksizegb
                    "VM Size" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
                    }
                $Result += @(New-Object pscustomobject -Property $props)
}

Write-Output $Result
```

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this script to achieve the same

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Azure-ARM-VM-Inventory-57ba01b7

Answer (score 2):

If you had read the documentation of the class you are already using ([DataDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.datadisk?view=azure-dotnet)) you could have noticed the [ManagedDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.manageddiskparameters?view=azure-dotnet) property which itself has another property named [StorageAccountType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.manageddiskparameters.storageaccounttype?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Compute_Models_ManagedDiskParameters_StorageAccountType) which contains the information you are looking for.

Something like this should do the trick (untested, might have to loop through `Datadisks` in case of multiple disks):

```
 $allvm = Get-Azurermvm | ForEach-Object { 
 $props = [ordered]@{
                    "Type" = $_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.ManagedDisk.StorageAccountType
                    "Name" = $_.name
                    "Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.disksizegb
                    "VM Size" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
                    }
                $Result += @(New-Object pscustomobject -Property $props)
}

Write-Output $Result
```

Comment: I know i haven't written what i have researched because i wanted to keep my post easy to read. I have tried the above class of datadisk and it is different class and not present under Get-Azurermvm.

In short StorageProfile.DataDisks.ManagedDisk.StorageAccountType
this doesn't work.

Comment: @aquib.rocks then post what you have tried, what errors you get etc. that is what the question should be